# Firebase Update using a String Object

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am making a simple program to log in tasks, when someone updates the field, I would like to update the document with only what was updated, thus I made a string generator that would create the parameters :

```
function fireBaseUpdateStringMaker(update_field,update_val)
{
  return '\''+update_field+'\''+' : '+'\''+update_val+'\''+','
}
```

which creates a field as such : 'update_field' : 'update_val'

Using this directly in my code works well if I follow the documentation from Firebase
db.collections('this_collection').doc('this_doc').update({ 'update_field' : 'update_val' })

but if I pass this to the update as a variable then it doesnt work

```
var updater =  'update_field' : 'update_val' ;
db.collections('this_collection').doc('this_doc').update({ updater })
```

I saw answers from other questions mentioned using square notation but using it here gives an error " ':' expected" , not putting the square notation creates a new field in my db called "updater" with content " 'update_field' : 'update_val' ".

Is there anyway to do this or should I simply just update every value everytime I'm editing a document? I'm quite new to NOSQL/Firebase so this is still not too intuitive for me. Any help is appreciated. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're doing isn't valid use of Firestore APIs.  You can't compose a string of field/value pairs - the document data must be a JavaScript object.  You have to populate a JavaScript object with the names of the fields a properties, along with their associated values.

This should work:

```
db.collection('this_collection').doc('this_doc').update({
    field: "value"
})
```

If you want to compose the object separately, do so as normal in JavaScript:

```
const data = { field: "value" }
db.collection('this_collection').doc('this_doc').update(data)
```

Comment: This works wonderfully! 

I'm not too familiar with object based programming, there are some values that are nested, such as

 { Dates : {
 DateCreated : <date>,
DateEdited : <date>
} 
}

I tried adding this to a variable as so: 
       updateObject.Date.DateCreated = <date>
but this gives an error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'DateCreated' of undefined", is this due to my semantics? Is there a workaround or a proper way to do this?

Comment: Nevermind, I think I got it, I made a new object inside the old one, seems to be right, thank you for helping me!

Comment: Great. The convention on Stack Overflow is to upvote and  accept answer that you found helpful, so that others can see that.